Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'identifier' at character position 0
i am facing the following error eventhough i don't have any pointcut logic in my spring boot application.
Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'identifier' at character position 0

i am using spring boot 2 and spring 5 version.
this is my exception stacktrace.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:277)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:805)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)
    at com.unifyia.credentialmanagement.CmsApp.main(CmsApp.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'identifier' at character position 0

along with the pointcut error i can see a bean creation error as meterRegistryPostProcessor
i don't have any logic as such for the above bean but still i am not able to fuguringout wheere it is being reffered and throwing these errors.
i completely stuck in this error. any help would be great appriciated.
i am using a gradle as a build tool. here my gradle.build dependencies
dependencies {
    // import JHipster dependencies BOM
    if (!project.hasProperty("gae")) {
        implementation platform("tech.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:${jhipsterDependenciesVersion}")
    }

    annotationProcessor "org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-jpamodelgen:${hibernateVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${projectLombokVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBootVersion}"

    // Use ", version: jhipsterDependenciesVersion, changing: true" if you want
    // to use a SNAPSHOT release instead of a stable release
    implementation "tech.jhipster:jhipster-framework"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate6"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc"
    implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui"
    implementation "com.zaxxer:HikariCP"
    implementation "org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:${jacksonDatabindNullableVersion}"
    implementation "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core"
    implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus"
    implementation "jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api"
    // Openapi generator uses javax namespace for now https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/13593
    implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2"
    implementation "javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final"
    implementation "com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine"
    implementation "com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.22.0"
    implementation "com.webauthn4j:webauthn4j-core:0.22.0.RELEASE"
    implementation "com.webauthn4j:webauthn4j-metadata:0.22.0.RELEASE"
    implementation "com.webauthn4j:webauthn4j-util:0.22.0.RELEASE"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3"
    implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.77"
    implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:1.77"
    implementation "org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi:21.0.1"
    implementation "org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core"
    implementation "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator"
    implementation "com.auth0:java-jwt:4.4.0"
    implementation files('lib/com/sun/imageio/1.1/imageio-1.1.jar')
    implementation "org.json:json:20240205"
    implementation "org.modelmapper:modelmapper:3.2.0"
    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstructVersion}"
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${projectLombokVersion}"

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server"

    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign"
    implementation "org.springframework.retry:spring-retry"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-data"

}


Please add your dependencies or rather build file to your question.

@M.Deinum, thanks for your reply. i update with the dependencies please have a look

Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

i am using spring boot version 3.2.0

Then why use incompatible libraries? Like javax.validation? I would suggest remove that API and hibernate-validator and replace with spring-boot-starter-validation. hibernate-core is already included in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. I also wonder if you have conflicting versions due to your spring-boot-configuration-processor having an explicit version. Finally also make sure you are compiling with the -parameters when using JDK17.

thanks, is the error occured because of these libraries..?

Not sure if it is those but they are incompatible, so there could be more incompatible versions/libraries in there.
